# Keras Add_loss throwing Operator Not allowed in Graph error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I created a basic loss function that takes the CDF (cumsum of pdf) and does a mean_squared error between the two.

Here is the code:

```
def tuner_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    y_actual=K.cumsum(y_true)
    y_pred=K.cumsum(y_pred)
    return K.mean(K.square(y_actual-y_pred))
```

I tried `model.add_loss(loss_model)` with `loss="None"` then tried
`loss=loss_model`, then commented out the `model.add_loss` and `loss_model` and directly put the  `tuner_loss` function into loss.

None of the them worked.

Here is that code:

```
input_layer= Input(179,)
y_actual=Input(199,)
x=Dense(32, activation='relu')(input_layer)
x=Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
x=Dense(32, activation='relu')(x)
x=Dropout(0.2)(x)
x=Dense(64)(x)
output_layer = Dense(199, activation='softmax')(x)
model=Model(inputs=[input_layer, y_actual], outputs=output_layer)
#loss_model= tuner_loss(y_actual, output_layer)
#model.add_loss(loss_model)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss= tuner_loss(y_actual,output_layer), metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I figure it has to be
something with how I'm manipulating the tf.tensors in the `tuner_loss`.
Here is error message I got running last code:

> "OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool`
>   is not allowed in Graph execution. Use Eager execution or decorate
>   this function with @tf.function.

I tried the decorator on the tuner, that also threw an error, so that didn't work.

Neither did enabling eager execution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use the standard?

```
model = Model(input_layer, output_layer)
model.compile(loss = tuner_loss, ...)
model.fit(input_data, output_data, ...)
```

Comment: Ok, I thought for some reason with this custom loss function that I need to pass in y_true, but I guess it makes sense that it could infer it like with a standard loss function. Thanks,